# Diabetic cat has stopped using litter box after having accidents

Tags: toilet-training, diabetes

My cat has adult-onset diabetes. It first manifested as having urine accidents which took me a while to notice as I lived in a carpeted apartment. At first these were unconscious accidents (i.e., he would simply be sitting somewhere and there would be a wet spot when he got up) but eventually he began intentionally urinating in the areas where he had urinated accidentally before. I took him to the vet and got him on insulin and the unintentional accidents stopped but he had become used to going on the carpet. He also began to poop on the carpet.

I thought that perhaps the problem was the smell of the urine attracting him back to those spots - though I tried to clean it I was never able to do so well enough.

A few months ago I moved to a new house which has hardwood floors. I thought that he would begin going in the box again but he has not. He just goes in random places on the floor. I clean them up and he doesn't return to the same spot but still ends up going on the floor. He has arthritis and I tried both the old and a new, lower-lipped litter box. He briefly began using the box again but then stopped and has resumed peeing and pooping all over in random places.

He's 17 years old but seems to be in good health other than the controlled diabetes and arthritis. Any ideas what I can do to get him to return to using the litter box?

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Did the vet also had a look for kidney stones?

Comment: What consistency does the cat litter have? I noticed that my cats prefer very fine litter. Maybe the coarser chunks are uncomfortable to walk on. Since he has arthrites, you need to make getting in and out of the box as easy as possible. If he has to lift his paws too much to get over the lip, consider crafting a step from an cardboard box.